# PostgreSQL jdbc driver maven 'latest' points to jre7, why?

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jdbc

The PostgreSQL jdbc driver has a sub-version for different jre-versions. The current, however, is java 8 and does not have an extra 'jre' tag.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I have this in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

However, the maven version plugin returns a different version:

```
 [INFO] The following dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions:
[...]
[INFO]   org.postgresql:postgresql ..................... RELEASE -> 42.2.5.jre7
```

Returns jre7 specific.

Does anyone know why? And how to switch to the default without explicitly coding the version in the pom?

Comment: I think this is an unfortunate consequence of PostgreSQL encoding the older Java version in their own version instead of using separate artifacts or qualifiers, while at the same time not doing that for the latest Java version supported. If you sort versions lexicographically then 42.2.4 simply comes earlier than 42.2.4.jre7, in other words, 42.2.4.jre7 'looks' newer. Posting as a comment as I'm not 100% sure, and I don't want to deepdive into how Maven determines what the latest release is..

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sounds very reasonable, thanks!